# New Safari App Extension Model: Perform Cross-Site HTTP-Request within browser's HTTP-Context

Tags: cookies, safari, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, safari-extension

I want to write a Safari Browser Extension on macOS (the latest extension model, https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariAppExtension_PG/) which needs to perform an HTTP-request within the browser's context (getting and setting cookies etc.) which is a cross origin request to another domain.

The Google Chrome extension model and the new Mozilla Firefox WebExtension model allow this by performing the request in the background page JavaScript of the extension.
The deprecated NPAPI model allows this directly with the native API provided by the browser.
The old Safari Extension model (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) also allows this in the background page JavaScript.

However, the new Safari Extension Model does not have background page scripts at all, as the "background" is directly the native sandboxed extension process.
In a content script of the extension I can perform an HTTP-request within the browser context, but I do not have cross domain permissions there.

I can perform HTTP-requests natively in the extension process (NSURLDownload, CFHttpStream, WebView object/NSMutableURLRequest, using cURL library, ...) but this has no connection to the browser's HTTP context.
I have not found any way to perform HTTP-requests via the Safari Services API (SFSafari*-classes).

Do I have to use the "old" Safari Extension model (Xcode 8.1 already does not allow me to add an "Safari Extension Companion" target to be used for the old model, there is only the new "Safari Extension" target)? I always want to use the newest technologies if possible.

Has anyone an idea?

Thank you for your hints,

Dominik

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this? Seems ridiculous that this isn't possible...

Comment: No, I could not find a way to do this so far. We still use the NPAPI technology in Safari.

Comment: Another thing we would need is accessing http-only cookies in the browser extension. The Google Chrome extension model and the Mozilla Firefox WebExtension model explicitly allow this via the `chrome.cookies` API (there is a flag `httpOnly` in the received cookies). In NPAPI this is possible by performing a request to the server and reading the cookies from the response headers as they are not filtered by the browser. But I have no idea how to do this in a safari extension.